# Stringbuilder adding % to end of URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I have a slight issue with a string being built in my code. When I debug my page the url is incorrect. For example Google's url is this when clicking on the link on my page. http://www.google.co.uk%22%22/

See below for code.

```
sb.Append(@"<a href=" + r["Url"].ToString() + "\"" + @""" target=""blank"">");
sb.Append(@"<img src=""../ShowImage.ashx?id=" + r["Image_id"] + "\" title=\"" + r["Title"].ToString() + "\"  alt=\"" + r["Alt_text"].ToString() + "\"  >");
sb.Append("</a>");
```

Is there a mistake in how I am building my string?

Thanks.

Comment: It's certainly not the stringbuilder's fault. What I notice is that you're `href` doesn't start with a `"`, and you're probably open to some form of html injection/xss.

Comment: sb.Append(@"<a href=""" + r["Url"].ToString() + @""" target=""blank"">");

Comment: Also, why are you contcatenating string even when using StringBuilder?

Comment: Btw `string.Format` makes code like this much more readable.

Comment: May want to look at sb.AppendFormat() to make this code easier to read

Comment: I suspect the place where you output the content of your string builder is responsible for the encoding.

Comment: This code was written a while ago and I am just refactoring it. Just noticed today url is not working so I would like it fixed. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing quotes escaped with `\` (`"\""`) with quotes escaped with " (`@"""`) and have one too many. Try this instead:

```
sb.Append(@"<a href=""" + r["Url"].ToString() + @""" target=""blank"">");
```

Answer (score 0):

`%22` is the string encoded version of `"`

Try:

```
sb.Append(@"<a href=" + r["Url"].ToString() + "\ + @""" target=""blank"">");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have any quotation mark before the URL, but you have two quotation marks after it. It's ok to omit the quotation marks (for values without spaces), but then you have to omit both of them. When you omit the starting quotation mark, the quotation mark (or in this case marks) at the end become part of the value.

Also, why are you concatenating strings, when you have a StringBuilder? Use the `Append` method directly instead of first concatenating strings, then appending the result.

```
sb
  .Append("<a href=\"").Append(r["Url"].ToString()).Append("\" target=\"blank\">")
  .Append("<img src=\"../ShowImage.ashx?id=").Append(r["Image_id"]).Append("\" title=\"").Append(r["Title"].ToString()).Append("\"  alt=\"").Append(r["Alt_text"].ToString()).Append("\">")
  .Append("</a>");
```